# Is it possible to retrieve the object instance performing a method call with AspectJ?

Tags: java, aspectj

Let's imagine the following aspect:

```
 aspect FaultHandler {

   pointcut services(Server s): target(s) && call(public * *(..));

   before(Server s): services(s) {
     // How to retrieve the calling object instance?
     if (s.disabled) ...;
   }

 }
```

The pointcut captures all calls to public methods of `Server` and runs the `before` advice just before any of these are called.

Is it possible to retrieve the object instance performing the call to the public `Server` method in the `before` advice? If yes, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use the this() pointcut :

```
pointcut services(Server s, Object o) : target(s) && this(o) && call....
```

Obviously, you can use a specific type instead of Object if you need to scope it.

EDIT

You can also use the thisJoinPoint variable :

```
Object o = thisJoinPoint.getThis();
```

While using thisJoinPoint often incur in a small performance penalty compared to using specific pointcuts, it can be used in case the caller is a static class.

In that case, there is no "this", so this(o) may fail to match, and thisJoinPoint.getThis() return null.

However, using :

```
Class c = thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getDeclaringType();
```

Will tell you the class that contains the static method. Exploring more fields on signature can also give you the method name etc..

Comment: So 'o' will be the caller of my method for sure? Even if the server method is called from static code?

Comment: @JVerstry: The [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html) states that the `this` pointcut "Will not match any join points from static contexts."

Comment: I think documentation means "in case of a static method execution, there is no this, so it can't be captured using this()".

Comment: JVersity, have you found a way of getting the static part, in case thisJoinPoint.getThis() returns null you should be able to use thisJoinPointStaticPart

Comment: @SimoneGianni what is `thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart`? Where is it defined?

Comment: thisJoinPoint and thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart are automatically available inside an advice, see here http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/language-thisJoinPoint.html